# Regex for this expression 'PI-1234-265K'

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression to validate the following codes, 
behind the code I stated the desired result.

```
<?php
    $codes[] = 'PI-1234-265K'; // true
    $codes[] = 'PIS2-12FG-265K'; // false
    $codes[] = 'PI-1234FG-265K'; // false
    $codes[] = 'PI-1234-2'; // false
    $codes[] = 'PI-1234-265K12313'; // true
    foreach($codes as $code){
        var_dump(preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}/', $code));
        echo '<br/>';
    }
?>
```

Currently the first part doesn't get checked properly, it returns 11001 but the desired result is 10001.

Comment: You've specified there are either two numbers, or two letters at the start, before the first "-". In one of your codes, there are four. There's something that jumped out at me anyway.

Comment: There is a good answer already, so no need to jump in. However, instead of [A-Za-z...] you can supply /i as a modifier to match case-insensitive, or use the shorter [\w\d]{2} instead. The full patter could look like this: `preg_match('#^[\w\d]{2}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{2,}$#i', 'PI-1234-265K')` (in this particular case the i modifier is superfluous)

Comment: @ExternalUse, you are correct with the `i` modifier, but the `\w` class does also include the underscore, if this is not wanted `\w` would be the wrong choice. The other thing is, `\w` does also include digits `\d`, so not need for `[\w\d]`.

Comment: Ooops, you're right of course, @stema. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) your regex

```
var_dump(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}$/', $code));
```

`^` is matching the start of the string

`$` is matching the end of the string

If you don't do this, you will get partial matches. Means in your second case "PIS2-12FG-265K" it matches **S2-12FG-265K**, so your match does not start at the beginning.